# datatables inline problem, i want to show all the actions in a single line. please see pics

Tags: jquery, css, laravel-5, datatables

i'm facing a problem with Datatables inline, I want to show my all actions in a single line. i tried inline CSS but no result. please help if it is possible, i attach the pics of Datatables and my code. Thanks

here is my code, in which i use foreach loop to display all the data in tabular form which comes from controller, problem is in the last `<td>`.

```
 <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr class="filters">
                                <th>Voucher#</th>
                                <th>Created Date</th>

                                <th>Package</th> 
                                <th>Mautamer's Name</th>
                                <th>Mautamer's Passport</th>
                                <th>Created By</th>
                                <th> Actions </th>      
                            </tr> 
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                             @foreach($vouchers as $voucher)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$voucher->id}}</td>
                                <td >{{$voucher->created_date}}</td>   
                                <td >{{$voucher->package_name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$voucher->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$voucher->passport_no}}</td>
                                <td>{{$voucher->created_by}}</td>
                                <td style="display:inline">

                                    <a href="{{route('voucher.show', $voucher->id)}}"> <i class="livicon" data-name="info" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#428BCA" data-hc="#428BCA" title="view" style='display:inline'></i></a>

                                    <a href="{{route('voucher.edit', $voucher->id)}}"><i class="livicon" data-name="edit" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#428BCA" data-hc="#428BCA" title="edit " style='display:inline'></i></a>
                                    <form method="{{route('voucher.destroy', $voucher->id)}}" action="" style='display:inline'>
                                        @method('Delete')
                                        <button type="submit"><i class="livicon" data-name="user-remove" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#f56954" data-hc="#f56954" title="delete"></i></button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach 

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

[Datatables pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Wmw.jpg)

Comment: Don't post picture of your code. Post your code here so it can be tested and corrected. Even better is to put it somewhere like JSFiddle. (I'm not the one down voted but probably that is why it was downvoted)

Comment: no problem bro, thank you.. i update the question please check now

Answer (score 0):

Add nowrap to the td that has buttons. and also give them some width.

```
<td style="display:inline"  nowrap>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i tried but again same output. I also tried the alternate css of nowrap "white-space:nowrap" and increase the width but same result. What should i do now?

Comment: obviously the sum of all widths are greater than the max allowed within column. Make sure you specify and force a width to each element so they are same sized and the sum is not greater than the column width.